# How to call startActivityForResult in class initialed from layout : main.xml

Tags: android, android-activity

this is the same question as "how can I retrieve data from the new one to the old one".

But in my first Activity, I called `setContentView(R.layout.main);`. There is a surfaceview drawing on canvas.

The only method I know is to call `getContext()` to get the context, then call `startActivity()`. But I can't call `startActivityForResult()` from the context I get, it seems that it doesn't support, I need to call it only in my activity class.

Can anyone give me any opinion?

EDIT:

Here is my code :

```
public class gameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    public gameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        //This is how I do : 
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getContext(), inputCharactorName.class);
        getContext().startActivity(intent);
        //This what I WANT to , but I don't know how
        //Activity.startActivityForResult(null,FPS);
        //I want to start the activity here;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem, but try `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Post some code that demonstrates the issue you are having, that might help people understand and answer (from the question, I don't know what you're asking, maybe code will help).

Comment: I use view.getContext() to return the view's Context. But it is not possible to call startActivityForResult(). I don't know why

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are completely sure that getContext() is an instance of an `Activity` then you can do:

```
((Activity)getContext()).startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Comment: After I called startActivityForResult(), my FPS suddenly drop from 60 to 18, do you know why??

Comment: it is the emulator's bug, after i test it on real device, it disappear, thx

Comment: It's the only solution, as I know, but this cast is dangerous :(

Comment: You can use `instance of` and it won't be dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone give me any opinion?

Call `startActivityForResult()` from your activity. Have your `SurfaceView` or whatever call a method on your activity that triggers the call to `startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: But the problem is I don't know how to call it. If know how to call, then the problem is solved.

Comment: After I called startActivityForResult(), my FPS suddenly drop from 60 to 18, do you know why??

Comment: I think the sub activity do slow down my main activity. I called finish though, but I don't know why it slow me down